# Writing regex to capture many different date formats

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression which will capture the following time formats:

```
H:MM
HH:MM
```

as well as variations with P.M or PM right after or with a space after the time, or in lower case, or with AM instead (hope you get the idea). As some examples:

```
1:00PM, 1:00pm, 1pm, 1PM, 1:00 PM, 1:00pm, 2:00
```

This is the regular expression I currently have:

```
([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9])?(( )?(PM|AM|am|pm|a.m|p.m|P.M|P.M|a.m.|p.m.|P.M.|A.M.))?
```

However while working for all my formats, it also captures every single other integer and I don't know how to fix that.

To combat this I've written 2 separate ones, one which captures just the time:

```
([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9])
```

and one which captures just the time with the PM/AM bit after:

```
([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9])?(( )?(PM|AM|am|pm|a.m|p.m|P.M|P.M|a.m.|p.m.|P.M.|A.M.)){1,2}
```

but ideally I want one expression for them all, however all my attempts have resulted to a similar result to the regex at the start of this post.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your expression can be greatly simplified using [regex flags](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Dinei it's in Python, I'll have a look at flags

Comment: Try this regex, I think it's simpler than what you have now. /^(0\d|1\d|2[0-3]|\d)(:[0-5]\d)?( *)?([AaPp]\.?[mM]\.?)?$/

Comment: The `.` character in your pattern (like `a.m|p.m`) needs a "\" character before (like `a\.m|p\.m`)

Comment: @TânNguyễn That's a very good spot, need to change that

Comment: Do you really want to match `14:00 PM`? Just making sure you have all cases covered.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is picking up individual characters as well, and 14:00 PM doesn't have to be matched, I wouldn't worry about it as it won't appear in my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex in python: `/((0\d|1\d|2[0-3]|\d)(((:[0-5]\d))|(\s*[AaPp]\.?[mM]\.?))+)/`
The first part matches the first part of the hour (HH or H), then next matches the minutes if any (:MM) and the last matches am, pm and their variances.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oPb7xb/2

Comment: This misses times such as 5:37, more concise than my solution though

Comment: sorry, depends on the formatting, however it still picks up individual integers that aren't time. If it's a time without a am/pm bit, it will always have a colon

Comment: @EchoTacticDouble You are correct. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\d{1,2}:\d{2}(\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)?
```

Explanation:

- `\d{1,2}` will match 1 or 2 digits (for hour).
- `:` will match literal `:`.
- `\d{2}` will match exact 2 digits (for minutes).
- `(\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)?`: will either take a match for `\s*[ap]\.?m\.?` or it won't, because of `?` after parenthesis. Now, let's break `\s*[ap]\.?m\.?` down a little:

  - `\s*` will match zero or more white-spaces. `\s` for white-spaces, and `*` for zero or more.
  - `[ap]` will expect either `a` or `p`.
  - `\.?` will match literal `.` and `?` makes it optional. Note that `.` in a regex matches anything, and to match the actual dot `.`, you have to do `\.`
  - `m` will expect a `m`
  - `\.?` again will match an optional `.`

And to allow case-insensitivity, you can compile this regex with `IGNORECASE` flag:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'\d{1,2}:\d{2}(\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)?', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: missing formats such as 1pm or 1PM and doesn't allow a space after the number such as 1 pm or 1PM but this is the closest, I'll see what I can do with this one

Answer (score 0):

I know you specifically asked for regex but I would be remiss if I didn't point out [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) parser was written with sort of thing in mind.  (depending on your end goal of course)

It does a REALLY good job of taking oddball date/time/datetime strings and converting them to datetime objects.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

times = [ "1:00PM", "1:00pm", "1pm",  "1PM", "1:00 PM", "1:00 AM", "1:00pm", "2:00"]

for t in times:
    x = parse(t)
    print(f"{x} <--> {t}")
```

output:

```
2018-11-21 13:00:00 <--> 1:00PM
2018-11-21 13:00:00 <--> 1:00pm
2018-11-21 13:00:00 <--> 1pm
2018-11-21 13:00:00 <--> 1PM
2018-11-21 13:00:00 <--> 1:00 PM
2018-11-21 01:00:00 <--> 1:00 AM
2018-11-21 13:00:00 <--> 1:00pm
2018-11-21 02:00:00 <--> 2:00
```

Comment: Would have used this but ideally I want to do it all using regular expressions, thank you though!

Comment: Understood.  I don't what you were doing with the values so this may not be a great option.  I've used this in cases where the datetime format is not always known or irregular.